# Why parent model in has_one association has foreign_key = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one

I've two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_address
  has_one :address


  def add_address
    self.address_id ||= Address.generate_new.id
  end
end
```

And

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.generate_new
    new_address = # some code generating UUID

    Address.create!({address: new_address})
  end
end
```

when I create User.new it creates address association, saves it, and I can fetch it with user.address and in mysql Address row has correct user_id, but User in mysql has address_id = nil. What I'm doing wrong? I've tried User.new\user.build_address both ways it creates and saves address but user always has address_id = nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way it is supposed to be.  From the [Rails Doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one)

> The distinction is in where you place the foreign key (it goes on the table for the class declaring the belongs_to association)

This means that since your `Address` model declares the `belongs_to`, that is where the foreign key should be placed.

What rails does behind the scenes when you search for `user.address` is does a search for the `Address` that has a `user_id` equal to the current `user`'s id.

Something like:

```
Select * From addresses where user_id = <current_user>.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have address_id column in user model? It should be enough for the association to have user_id on the address table.